# How can I set protected properties of mocks for abstract classes?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I've looked around and I found a solution that works for normal objects, but it doesn't seem to work for mocks.

The test below fails with the message: `Unable to set property someProperty of object type Mock_ClassToTest_40ea0b83: Property someProperty does not exist`.

```
class sampleTestClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function test() {
        $object = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(ClassToTest::class, [], '', false);
        $this->setProtectedProperty($object, 'someProperty', 'value');
    }

    private function getReflectionProperty($object, $property) {
        $reflection         = new ReflectionClass($object);
        $reflectionProperty = $reflection->getProperty($property);
        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
        return $reflectionProperty;
    }

    /**
     * This method modifies the protected properties of any object.
     * @param object $object   The object to modify.
     * @param string $property The name of the property to modify.
     * @param mixed  $value    The value to set.
     * @throws TestingException
     */
    function setProtectedProperty(&$object, $property, $value) {
        try {
            $reflectionProperty = $this->getReflectionProperty($object, $property);
            $reflectionProperty->setValue($object, $value);
        }
        catch ( Exception $e ) {
            throw new TestingException("Unable to set property {$property} of object type " . get_class($object) .
                                       ': ' . $e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
        }
    }
}

abstract class ClassToTest
{
    private $someProperty;
    abstract function someFunc();
}

class TestingException extends Exception
{
}
```

EDIT: 8/31/2016 4:32 PM EST
Updated code in response to [answer by Katie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257217/how-can-i-set-protected-properties-of-mocks-for-abstract-classes/39257527#39257527).

Comment: why are you testing an abstract class?

Comment: That way I won't have to write extra test cases for the classes that extend them.

Comment: You still have to write test cases for the classes that extend an abstract class. They implement the abstract functions of the base class and there is no way to test those functions by testing the base class.

Comment: Agree with @axiac, you may be able to hit parts of the abstract class, but in the end, you will still have to test the classes that extend it.

Comment: I have a bunch of abstract classes that only have one or two abstract methods. Some of those methods are extremely simple and require little or no testing.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call Reflection methods on a mocked object, instead, you can call it on the abstract class itself:

So change:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
```

to

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass(ClassToTest::class);
```

And that will work for anything that is not abstract in the class, such as your property, or another method that is fully implemented.

**Additional Note since OP was updated**

The fix will still work for your first line in the getReflectionProperty.  But if you don't have access to the class name, then that is a problem.

Comment: That does work, but this was a simplifed version of the actual code that I use. In the real case, the class name is not available. I updated the OP.

Comment: I have a method that takes an object, a property, name and a value and sets the object's property accordingly. I don't want to have to change the method signature.

Comment: You need the class name to do a proper reflection of the class, getting it from PHPUnit's produces this error: Unable to set property someProperty of object type Mock_ClassToTest_27fdf591: Property someProperty does not exist. The object type is not the same as your class.

Comment: In general, this probably isn't such a good idea, but wanted to show you how to do it.  Mocking an abstract class for testing is probably rife with grief, but it depends on the situation, and how much of the class is abstract or how much the methods are interdependent.

Answer (score 3):

Using reflection to access protected and private properties and methods of classes in tests seems a very clever method but it leads to tests that are difficult to read and understand.

On the other hand, only the public interface of a class should be tested. Testing (and even caring about) the protected and private properties and methods of the tested class is a sign that the tests are written after the code. Such tests are brittle; any change in the implementation of the tested class breaks the tests, even when it doesn't break the functionality of the class.

There is usually no need to test an abstract class. Most of the times the tests of its children classes cover the relevant code of the abstract class too. If they doesn't cover some part of it then either that code is not needed there or the test cases do not cover all the corner cases.

However, sometimes one needs to write a testcase for an abstract class. The best approach, in my opinion, is to extend the abstract class at the bottom of the file that contains the test case, provide simple implementations for all its abstract methods and use this class as [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test).

Something along these lines:

```
class sampleTestClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $object = new ConcreteImplementation();
        $result = $object->method1();
        self::assertTrue($result);
    }
}

class ConcreteImplementation extends AbstractClassToTest
{
    public function someFunc()
    {
        // provide the minimum implementation that makes it work
    }
}
```

You are testing a mock in the code you posted. The mocks are not meant to be tested. Their purpose is to simulate the behaviour of the collaborators of the SUT that are not appropriate to be instantiated in a test.

The reasons why a collaborator class is mocked in a test include, but are not limited to:

- difficult creation; for example, when the constructor of the mocked class requires many arguments or other objects;
- the collaborator is an abstract class or an interface; the actual implementation might not even exist when the test and the tested class are written;
- the code of the collaborator takes a lot of time to complete or requires additional resources (disk space, database connection, Internet connection etc);
- the code of the collaborator has permanent side effects; this is usually coupled with the previous reason.